# SHA256 different hash in nodejs and kotlin

Tags: java, node.js, kotlin, sha256

I am using a SHA 256 hash generator in two different modules. One module is written in Kotlin and the other one using the nodejs crypto API. The hashed value is slightly different in nodejs and kotlin.

Kotlin Code

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.util.Base64
fun main() {
        val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
        val input = "test".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
        val bytes = md.digest(input)
        println(Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(bytes))
}
```

Nodejs code

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');

hash.update('test');
console.log(crypto.createHash('sha256').update('test', 'utf8').digest('base64'));
```

The kotlin code outputs `n4bQgYhMfWWaL-qgxVrQFaO_TxsrC4Is0V1sFbDwCgg=` where as the nodejs code outputs `n4bQgYhMfWWaL+qgxVrQFaO/TxsrC4Is0V1sFbDwCgg=`. I couldn't identify what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue is caused by the urlencoded base64 provided by kotlin: `Base64.getUrlEncoder()`.

In kotlin you are getting the base64 url encoded, while at node you only got base64.

Maybe this helps you to determine if the assumption is correct.
Add the url encoding at node:

```js
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64url


const base64url = require('base64url');
console.log(base64url(crypto.createHash('sha256').update('test', 'utf8')));
```

Comment: It almost worked. Now i am getting n4bQgYhMfWWaL-qgxVrQFaO_TxsrC4Is0V1sFbDwCgg as the output with node and n4bQgYhMfWWaL-qgxVrQFaO_TxsrC4Is0V1sFbDwCgg= as the output for kotlin. The = is missing in the node version.  I will keep investigating. Thanks a lot

Comment: The =. is something that java/kotlin adds regardless of the input string. I will probably append = for the node version. I will keep looking at the reason for =.

Comment: the = is a value for padding. Not getting deep into technicals, it serves as a padding.  If your implementation considers padding, it will put one or two "=" to output the proper length.

Answer (score 2):

You've to use `getEncoder()` instead of `getUrlEncoder()` in your kotlin code.

So here is the working code snippet

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.util.Base64

fun main() {  
    val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
    val input = "test".toByteArray()
    val bytes = md.digest(input)
    println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes))
}
```

And for NodeJS

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const generateSignature = (body) => {
  const payload = body;
  const signature = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(payload).digest('base64')
  return signature;
}

console.log(generateSignature("test"));
```